# Websocket App Design

Tags: node.js, web, websocket

Most examples I have seen are are just small demo's and not full stack applications and they use websocket for messaging, but for any chat application there is more data then just messages...suppose like user profile, his contacts etc.

**So should I use websockets for all communication between server and client or just use them for sending messages and do other things through http?** If I am to use websocket for all communication how do url design of the app...since websockets don't have have any different urls like http.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/), an officially registered WebSocket subprotocol that provides applications with WebSocket based

- asynchronous, bidirectional remote procedure calls
- real-time publish & subscribe notifications

Disclaimer: I am original author of WAMP and work for Tavendo.

Comment: So you claim its possible to have the whole app in WebSocket? rather than having http and websockets for just messages?

Comment: Yes, for a browser client and a single page Web UI the only work for HTTP is getting the static Web assets like HTML, JS, PNG, .. files. You can have all your app communication running over WebSocket. No need for Ajax or any kind of HTTP.

Comment: And what about security?

Comment: Yes, security is important.

Comment: Is it secure enough on using just websockets for all communication

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you'll get the usual "it depends" answer, because, well, it depends!

If you are going to build a large application, to be used by a number of different clients in different network arrangements etc then I personally wouldn't recommend using WebSockets for everything. Why?

- It's a new standard, so not all clients support it
- In some network configurations WebSocket traffic *may* be filtered out, meaning you end up with no communications - not great
- If you end up exposing an external API then HTTP is much better fitted for the job and will likely be easier to code against. There are a lot more tools out there to help you with it and styles that everyone is familiar with, like REST, to follow.

Use WebSockets when you require data being pushed from the server without the client having to poll for it, or when HTTP header overhead becomes a problem. And if you still decide to use it make sure you have a fallback mechanism (e.g. longpolling)  so you don't end up with no comms.

I'm afraid I can't help you regarding WebSocket API design... given it's a new standard I don't believe the community has settled on anything just yet so you'll have to come out with your own message-based scheme.